# @DirtiesContext not clearing database

Tags: java, spring

I have tried the following steps but no luck sadly :

Method number 1 always fail because size expected 1 but its 2  -> test runned individually passing through successfully but when i run all application tests then exactly that one is failing

1)Mark each method with  `@DirtiesContext(methodMode = DirtiesContext.MethodMode.BEFORE_METHOD)`

2)Mark at class level `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`

3)Mark methods with `@Transactional`

```
  @SpringBootTest
public class ExportServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    ExportService exportService;

    @Autowired
    ExportRepository exportRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;


    @Test
    public void onlyOneExportUserShouldBeAddedWithMultipleEntries() {
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity().setId(2L);
        exportService.createIfNotExist(userEntity);
        exportService.createIfNotExist(userEntity);
        Assertions.assertThat(exportRepository.findAll()).hasSize(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void exportUserShouldBeAdded() {
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity().setId(1L);
        exportService.createIfNotExist(userEntity);
        Optional<UserExportEntity> exportUser = exportRepository.findByUserEntityId(userEntity.getId());
        Assertions.assertThat(exportUser).isPresent();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldHaveTwoRecordsInExport() {
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity().setId(1L).setEmail("test@test.com");
        UserEntity userEntity2 = new UserEntity().setId(2L).setEmail("test1@test.com");
        userRepository.save(userEntity);
        userRepository.save(userEntity2);
        exportService.createIfNotExist(userEntity2);
        exportService.createIfNotExist(userEntity);
        Assertions.assertThat(exportRepository.findAll()).hasSize(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you persist things in the database then restarting the application (`@DirtiesContext`) will obviously not help. Either make all tests transactional or write your test in such a way that it doesn't matter if there is additional data or not.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for your comment , i have tried annotating each test with Transactional in that test class but it did not work unfortunately

Comment: That will only work if the service methods operate in the same transaction, so if they start a new transaction or work around Spring it won't work. So either that are transaction with `REQUIRES_NEW`, you are doing something to bypass Spring (work with connections yourself, mess around with transactions) or finally you are using MySQL with MyISAM tables (which doesn't support transactions).

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you so much for your effort,I have set Transactional on a single method and it went through sucessfully, not sure why it did not at first, could you maybe explain in few words what Transactional will do to a test

Comment: It will rollback all changes after the test has finished, leaving the db in a clean state. Just mark the whole test class `@Transactional` to not leave state in the database (and stop using `@DirtiesContext` as you won't need it).

Comment: @M.Deinum you have helped a lot thank you